# Create sparse cross table in R from lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I can't reproduce a sample, but here is my problem.

I have a large list object (1.1GB, ~ 3 million elements). It looks not dissimilar to this:

```
> head(xx, n = 3)
[[1]]
[1] "Start"                                                                                                                     
[2] "A|B|C"  
[3] "C|C|B"
[4] "Lose"                                                                                                                

[[2]]
[1] "Start"                                          
[2] "B|NULL|NULL"
[3] "Lose"                                    

[[3]]
[1] "Start"                                               
[2] "C|NULL|NULL"
[3] "Win"
```

What I want to do is count the number of transitions between each step within the nested list, i.e. how often Start goes to C|Null|Null, how often C|Null|Null goes to Win, across the massive list.

On a small subsample, I can use the following (where the Placeholder offsets the lists by one):

```
Transition <-  table(From=unlist(lapply(xx, append, 'Placeholder', 0L)),
                       To=unlist(mapply(c, xx, 'Placeholder')))
```

which creates a large contingency table object, where most of the table is populated with zeroes. However, on real-world data, this object easily exceeds 2Gb and often fails with an unable to create object memory error.

On my small subsample again, I revert the cross table to a data.frame() object which coerces the cross table back to a three column table (From, To, Freq), and can manually delete zero entries along with my placeholder.

My question then is: is there a way to achieve a "sparse" data frame which counts real transitions but skips creating the huge zero-padded cross table?

Please let me know if you need more information and I will try to provide!

Answer (score 0):

Solved myself in a different way using data.table for speed:

```
sequence <- unlist(xx)
Transition <- data.table(
                 From = head(sequence, -1L),
                   To = tail(sequence, -1L))
Transition.count <- Transition[, .N, by = c('From', 'To')]
```